# Haystack: indexing only some entries

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using Haystack to perform searches on my website and one of the models being searched has a field

```
searchable = models.BooleanField()
```

Is it possible to tell Haystack to index only the entries having

```
searchable = True
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need [`index_queryset`](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#index-queryset)

```
class YourIndex(...):
    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return YourModel.objects.filter(searchable=True)
```

Comment: For my case, when I save an entry with `searchable = False` it will be indexed. And when `update_index` is used, the filter mentioned in `index_queryset` is applied and only the indexes with `searchable = True` will be updated. But still there are entries in the search index with `searchable = False` (added while saving the entry), Is it possible to avoid this ?

Comment: @NEB Can you elaborate on the version of `django-haystack` you are using? Perhaps the items with `False` `searchable` are items added before you add a `index_queryset`, try to rebuild all the index?

Comment: I'm using haystack-v2.1.0 and django-v1.7. Rebuilding index(uses `update_index`) gives proper index(its not a problem), but I'm concerned with the new entries with default `searchable` set to `false`. I tried with both `RealtimeSignalProcessor` and also `CelerySignalProcessor`(celery-v3.1.15) the issue is still the same. But with `CelerySignalProcessor` I'm facing one more issue as mentioned in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223369), (this is due to the presence of transaction block and mostly the failure of `djcelery_transactions`, because of new DB changes in django-v1.7)